# How to use module with different sub-templates

Tags: php, opencart

I want to display existing module in two different places with two different views.
Of course i can create another module, but this doesn't look right, because logic is the same.
On the other side i want to be able to reuse both views, but it looks like i can reuse only modules with hard-wired templates, am I right? Or how can i do it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want to (for example) show the module in content_bottom on one page, and content_left on another page? And you want the module to use a different template depending on where it's positioned?

Comment: @rjdown That's exactly what's being asked here.

Comment: Not exactly, i just wanted an option to change the view, not specifically depending on position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your module's controller, you'll have something like this:

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleMyModule extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
```

If it just says `index()` then change it to `index($setting)`

`$setting['position']` will contain the name of the position for the current instance, e.g. "content_bottom". So you can just change template based on this.

A basic example:

```
switch($setting['position']) {
    case 'content_top':
        $template_name = 'my_module_top.tpl';
        break;
    case 'column_left':
        $template_name = 'my_module_left.tpl';
        break;
    default:
        $template_name = 'my_module.tpl';
        break;
}

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/' . $template_name)) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module' . $template_name;
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/module/' . $template_name;
}
```

Comment: can i manually set fields in $setting? because it will be more convemient if it will depend not on position, but on something that i can change from template

Comment: The fields come from the data collected on the module's config page. If you want a new setting you should be able to add it there easily enough. Shout if you need help.

Comment: $setting['position'] is just doestn't work. It shows 'Notice: Undefined index' at this line

Comment: Do you have an admin page for your module, where you can apply it to different layouts?

Comment: yes. sorry, i misunerstoos question at first. it's standert module, and it have only disabled/enabled setting at admin page

Comment: ahh ok, you're going to need to copy the code from another module (category is a good one) so you have somewhere to set per-layout settings like this http://i.imgur.com/27yWuLq.png and then you can tweak it to add a template option like this http://i.imgur.com/D9VFN8V.png - is this what you had in mind?